# All levels of variable predicted when reference level has no observations in fixed effect regression

Tags: r, marginal-effects, fixest, r-marginaleffects

I am using the `marginaleffects` package to calculate the conditional marginal effects of a particular fixed effect regression using the `fixest` package.

My code looks like the following:

```
library(marginaleffects)
library(tidyverse)
library(fixest)


reg <- feols(data = data, DV ~ var1:(var3 + control) + var3 + var1:var2 + var2 + control | year , vcov="cluster")


plot_cme(reg,variables = c("var3"), condition = list("var1"), draw = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(type = case_when(contrast == "type2 - type1" ~ "type2",
                                 contrast == "type3 - type1" ~ "type3",
                                 contrast == "type4 - type1" ~ "type4",
                                 contrast == "type5 - type1" ~ "type5")) %>% ggplot(aes(x=var1,y=estimate,ymin=conf.low,ymax=conf.high)) + facet_wrap(~type) + geom_point() + geom_errorbar() + theme_light()
```

The variable `var1` is intentionally interacted with `var3` and `var2` without the uninteracted effect because it is dependent on var3, and there would thus be perfect collinearity.

All this code works, but I know that this version of the dataset `data` does not have any observations where the reference level for the categorical variable `var3` (ref = type1) is present. All observations of `var3` are "type2", "type3", "type4" or "type5". Yet I can plot CMEs and get `summary()` estimates for all 4 other "types" of `var3`, both interacted and non-interacted. I do not understand how this is possible. How can you calculate these effects with no reference level to compare them against?

Is this cased by the use of fixed effects for `year`, since that eliminates the intercept? If that is the case, then how do I interpret the results from `plot_cme()`? What are the marginal means estimates with respect to, if the reference category is no longer present?

If I look at the `plot_cme` output setting draw=false like so:

```
plot_cme(reg,variables = c("var3"), condition = list("var1"), draw = FALSE)
```

It lists the column "var3" as "type2" for all the rows. This would seem to indicate that the reference level has been changed to "type2". Yet I still have a contrast for "type2 - type1". How is this possible? And how can I interpret the marginal effects assuming this model is correct?

Comment: I believe that the `var3` column is an artefact of the data building process, and that it is not actually used in computation in this case, because internally `marginaleffects` computes predictions on two datasets ("high" and "low"), with synthetic values of `var3` set to the levels of interest.